# MS Access VBA modify Excel sheet without writing to Drive

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Not sure if this fix is possible, but worth a shot.

I have a VBA module in my Access database to export some query results to a preexisting Excel sheet. I had no problem creating a new sheet in my C: drive and populating that with the query results. But I need to be able to modify an existing Excel sheet.

This database will be used by many users at the same company. They will download a zip with the database and a few Excel sheets with tables and charts referencing those tables. The tables will be populated by query results from Access.

The main issue is that with my current code, I am getting runtime error `3011` where Access can't find the query `tempQ1`. Here is my code: (sorry if it's messy)

```
Sub QueryExport()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tempQ1 As DAO.QueryDef
Dim tempQ2 As DAO.QueryDef
Dim totalFindingsQuery As String
Dim breakdownFindingsQuery As String

Dim query1Name As String
Dim query2Name As String
query1Name = "tempQ1"
query2Name = "tempQ2"

Set db = CurrentDb

totalFindingsQuery = "<SQL QUERY>"
breakdownFindingsQuery = "<SQL QUERY>"

Set tempQ1 = db.CreateQueryDef(query1Name, totalFindingsQuery)
Set tempQ2 = db.CreateQueryDef(query2Name, breakdownFindingsQuery)

'filepath will change to variable to accomodate various users
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, queryName1, "C:\Documents\ <etc.>", True

DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "tempQ1"
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "tempQ2"

End Sub
```

I looked at this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8cac5693-a620-4511-8784-2659904d6481/transfertext-runtime-error-3011?forum=accessdev and found what I think my issue is -- When looking at the Properties of my C: drive, I only have "Special Permissions" checked, and I don't think I have write permissions. I cannot get this changed due to corporate policy (and none of my users can either), so I need to figure out how to modify an Excel sheet on a local drive without needing Write permissions. Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please state the full error message. -- AFAIK, you can't use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport` to edit an existing file, it always creates a new file. -- If you can't write a folder, you can't export there. But I'm not sure that is your actual problem.

Comment: The actual error text is --  "the MS Access database engine could not find the object "tempQ1." Make sure the object exists and that you spell it's name and the path correctly. If 'tempQ1' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server admin." What command should I use to edit an existing file? I guess I can write to the folder then because I wasn't having issues before when I was creating a new sheet with the TransferSpreadsheet cmd

Comment: Would it make sense to create variable `wb` that equals the sheet I want to modify, then doing something like `wb.Range("A1").copyfromrecordset rs` where I set the query I want equal to `rs`, a recordset?

Comment: Re-reading your code, try putting `db.QueryDefs.Refresh` between `db.CreateQueryDef` and `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`

Comment: I still don't exactly understand your question. You should have write permissions on the folder where your Access database is located, else it would be impossible to open it. You can't modify a file without write permission, but you also can't run Access without write permission, thus you should have it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately the same error persists on the same line...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, I figured out that it's not a permissions error and I definitely do have write permissions as I was able to perform other tasks that require them, but the error still exists and I can't figure out what the issue is. See some of the above comments for the error text. Is it possible that I'm not creating the query titled "tempQ1" correctly? Or should I be using a different command to edit an existing spreadsheet instead of TransferSpreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Well, spotted your error, and it's a simple one:

In `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, queryName1, "C:\Documents\ <etc.>", True` replace `queryName1` with `query1Name`.

And for future reference, include Option Explicit in any module to avoid variable misspelling

Comment: Damn, so easy to see yet so easy to miss... My standard blurb for Option Explicit: -- Put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module. 
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. 
This is really a must have for VBA development.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I actually had the correct name in my actual code, I edited the code I posted a lot to remove company IP stuff and made the error then. I ended up finding a solution by removing the `TransferSpreadsheet` command, and opening Excel, opening the workbook, opening the necessary worksheet, setting each query as a recordset, then setting the workbook.Range().copyfromrecordset

Comment: Well, your code is valid and working, as long as the `<etc,>` ends with a `filename.xlsx`